# Overwrite Python os library in all dependencies

Tags: python, python-os

I am using official libraries from pypi that heavily relly on `os` lib for open, isfile, makedirs and so on which is quiet limited if you want to work with GCS, S3 or other cloud based storages. I do not want to mess with internals of official libraries, but have a quick patch that would make all the imported libraries fall back to my implementation. Let's say 
`os.path.isfile = my_isfile_fun`, but only when `path` starts with `gs://` or `s3://` otherwise it uses standard library (I do not want to break it completely). Is there a way to do that? Also, I do not want to modify the whole library, but just some functions.

Here is the scenario

```
import some_pypi_module # <--- it uses os library

some_pypi_module.save(path) # <--- is saves to the path on disk using os library
```

My desired scenario

```
# do something to patch os
#
import some_pypi_module # <--- it uses modified os library

some_pypi_module.save(path) # <--- is saves to the path on disk using modified os library and now can understand gs://
```

Comment: If you're using AWS services such as S3 with python you should be using [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's a good idea, but it is possible to redefine functions and variables from imported modules after importing them. Hree is an example using `numpy`:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.pi
3.141592653589793
>>> np.pi = 4
>>> np.pi
4
>>> np.sin(0)
0.0
>>> np.sin = lambda x : x+1
>>> np.sin(0)
1
```

A possible soulution could thus be to perform the check with an `if` statement in the files you need, and then make the necessary adjustments.

Again, however, I'm not sure how good an idea this really is, as it could lead to some very puzzling bugs down the line.

Comment: will it work if I do this: `import os; os.path.isfile = my_isfile_fun` and then import other library which uses `os`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that part of your question. In that case, I don't know what will happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the patching in following ways:

```
import os
os.path.isfile_old = os.path.isfile

def my_isfile_fun(path):
    if(path.startswith(('s3://', 'gs://')):
        #use boto3 head object or your logic that you wish to implement
    else:
        return os.path.isfile_old(path)

os.path.isfile = my_isfile_fun
```

Now when you trigger

```
os.path.isfile(path)
```

It will return value accordingly

Hope it helps